# IgniteQueue getting - SparkException: Task not serializable

Tags: apache-spark, ignite

When we use IgniteQueue inside Spark map as below

```
sparkDataFrame.map(row => {
  igniteQueue.put(row)
})
```

we get SparkException: Task not serializable exception. This is because IgniteQueue is not Serializable.

Is there a way to make IgniteQueue serializable?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to serialize IgniteQueue, you need to take it inside spark task, right from ignite instance, for example:

```
JavaIgniteContext<Integer, Integer> igniteContext = new JavaIgniteContext<Integer, Integer>(
                sparkContext,"examples/config/spark/example-shared-rdd.xml", false);
Ignite ignite = igniteContext.ignite();
IgniteQueue queue = ignite.queue(name, cap, null);
```

Also, you can get information about integration Ignite with spark [here](https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/ignitecontext-igniterdd)

Answer (score 0):

Is your class implements as serializable ? if not then make that class serializable and check. which dependences you used for ignite-spark and what version ?